# JavaFX OSX WebView CSS opacity not working

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am using JRE 8_40 on OSX for a JavaFX application which is using WebView to display a HTML form written using AngularJS and Bootstrap.  I have found the form submit button which uses AngularJS "ng-disabled" and class="btn btn-success btn-lg" is hidden when in the disabled state.  When the button enters the enabled state the button displays correctly.

I have narrowed the problem down to the opacity CSS Setting for the Bootstrap .btn.disabled class.

If I have the following style on the button as per the bootstrap css, the button does not display

```
<input type="button" value="TEST" style="opacity: .65">
```

The opacity style works correctly on the same version of the JRE on Windows.

Is there a display setting required within the JavaFX application on OSX?

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems with transparency, I tried the following on OSX 10.10.4 with JDK 1.8_51:

```
public class JavaFXTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Transparency Test");

        BorderPane content = new BorderPane();
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

        URL url = getClass().getResource("/transparent.html");
        webEngine.load(url.toExternalForm());

        content.setCenter(webView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(content, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

the file *transparent.html* is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2  style="opacity: 1">transparency test 1</h2>
    <h2  style="opacity: .65">transparency test 0.65</h2>
    <h2  style="opacity: 0.33">transparency test 0.33</h2>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="1" style="opacity: 1">
        <input type="button" value="0.65" style="opacity: .65">
        <input type="button" value="0.33" style="opacity: .33">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Program shows the following WebView:

[image: screenshot of program]

I have not tried with 1.8_40, could you update to the latest Java version?

Comment: I have tried your code with my Netbeans project and it doesn't work for me.  When I run my application I only see "transparency test 1" and button "1".  I have updated my jdk to java "1.8.0_51" and my Mac has version OSX 10.10.4.  I have made sure my compiled jar file is run with the latest version by supplying the full path on the command line to the java executable.

Comment: Strange. I will try it on a different machine next week when I am back from my vacation.

Comment: I also opened a ticket with openjdk some time ago [link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087369). The history of the ticket shows they reproduced the issue and targeted Java 9 for a fix but now they are reporting that they can't reproduce the issue with 10.9.4.  Is this more of a OSX issue?  I am using a Macbook Pro.

Comment: what happens if you open the html file in a browser? Is transparency working then?

Comment: So, I tested the program and the html file on two MBPs, one from late 2007, one from mid 2013, both running now 10.10.5 and JDKs 1.8.0_51 and 1.8.0_60 as well as using Safari, Chrome and Firefox. In all combinations the transparency was working. So you should make sure that the thml file works with your browsers, otherwise it might be a problem with the graphics of your system.

Comment: When I open the html file in Safari, Chrome and Firefox the transparency is working ok.  I've updated to 1.8.0_60 and still have the same problem.  My webEngine getUserAgent() method returns _User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) JavaFX/8.0 Safari/538.19_

Comment: That is strange, I have the same user agent, 1.8.0_60 running OSX 10.10.5. No matter how I start the app, from IDEA or from the terminal with the java command, transparency is working in JavaFX for me as it is in the browsers.

Comment: A friend just tried on his MBP with 1.8.0_51 and it worked there as well.

Comment: I'm wondering now if it is something to do with the updating of the JDK and certain files not being updated.  I'll download the tar.gz version of the JRE and install it and run my jar file using the JRE.

Comment: I don't think it's something like that because the webkit component is included as a binary buried deep with in the JDK, here it's at /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjfxwebkit.dylib. You might try to test the html file with Webkit itself, available at http://www.webkit.org to see if this works.

Comment: A friend compiled the code and ran on his MBP.  It didn't work as expected as he had 1.8.0_40.  We installed 1.8.0_51 from the zip file download available on the Oracle website and unzipped into his home folder and ran the jar file again this time executing the 1.8.0_51 java executable.  It still didn't work which was very suprising and perplexing that his MBP also behaves the same as mine.

Comment: I also downloaded version r189569 of WebKit and the transparency on the HTML file works OK on my MBP.

Comment: So the only difference I see now is that you installed the JDK from the zip version and I and my friend use the dmg. Seems I'm on the end of ideas. Sorry if I couldn't help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem with "opacity", this is what worked for me.

```
"rgba(r,g,b,a)"
```